# PHPUnit: how to test commands or functions that modify state?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cqrs

Trying to get into Unit Testing. Since I'm also implementing CQRS, I was wondering how I would test something like this:

```
class CommandHandler{
  private $repository;
  public function __construct( $repository ){
    $this->repository = $repository;
  }
  public function handle( $command ) {
    $Entity = new Entity( $command->getSomething() );
    $this->repository->add( $Entity );
  }
}
```

Taken that Unit Testing is about testing the public API of my classes, what exactly would I want to test here? That an instance of `Entity` is passed to the repository?

Comment: Even better you can use type hints here and then there's no need to write a test.

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv And apart from this specific example, how do you test methods that do not return something?

Comment: You mock the "repository" and spy on what is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Trying to get into Unit Testing. Since I'm also implementing CQRS, I was wondering how I would test something like this

The two presentations you want to watch:

- Katrina Owen: [467 Tests, 0 Failures, 0 Confidence](https://vimeo.com/channels/752582/68730418)
- Sandi Metz: [Magic Tricks of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M)

The TL;DR of both talks is: [image: an origin vs type matrix].

Query messages and command messages sent *to* the subject of the test are asserted by querying the state of the test subject.  *Command messages* sent *by* the test subject are verified by expectation -- you confirm that the correct message was sent, without worrying about the effects of that message.

So the answer to your question depends in part on whether or not, for this test, the repository is part of the system under test, or part of [the boundary](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries).  If the repository is part of the system under test, then you can treat the entire test as verification of an incoming message, and query the state of the repository.  If the repository is part of the boundary (if it is provided by the test), then you test the expectation -- was the method on the repository invoked correctly?

In the latter case, there is an additional interesting question: is the need to verify the expectation a code smell?  It could be that the test -- by inducing a check against an expectation -- is actually revealing a problem in the design; maybe there should be more *instrumentation* in the command handler itself, so that the test can query the command handler itself to find out what messages have been sent.  Scott Bellware's [Doctrine of Useful Objects](https://github.com/eventide-project/docs/blob/master/user-guide/useful-objects.md) explores this idea.

Comment: I'm going to watch these vids. What exactly are "direct public side effects"?